# ReplaceAll for big comma separated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, replaceall

I have used the `replaceAll` method of Javascript to replace the occurrences of character code `&#34;` to Double Quotes in a big comma separated String. I really worry whether it will cause any issues or performance issues when deal with large amount of data.

Data will be like below:-

```
"TEST,TEST,&#34;TEST&#34;,TEST,
TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,
&#34;TEST&#34;,TEST,TEST,TEST,
.
.
.Many Rows
.
&#34;TEST&#34;,TEST,TEST,TEST"
```

My JavaScript code:-

```js
data = data.replaceAll('&#34;','"');
```

Please guide me if there is a better way to do this or this is really good approach?

Comment: Don't worry about performance before you've done any measurements.

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me.  Do you have any other requirements?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have done testing up to 50k rows and looks fine. However, I want to ensure this is good or is there any better approaches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks... I have to render this data as table in the page, already completed that part.

Comment: "Painting" a table _"with up to 50k rows"_ will take sooo much more time compared to a simple `.replaceAll()`

Comment: @Andreas I have used pivottable.js  so it will not display information all at a time but when user drag and drop a column.

Comment: My basic test shows that doing a `replaceAll` on 50K rows takes 4ms. 150K took 12ms.

Answer (score 0):

ReplaceAll function was deprecated and not supported for IE browser.

I have used regEx with replace function to do this and working fine.

```
if(data  && data.indexOf('&#34;') >= 0)
     data = data.replace(/&#34;/g,'"');
```